# Integrating with universal substitution

Tags: integration, trigonometry

$$\int \frac{1-3\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)}dx  $$

I have a homework question solving this problem with universal substitution.

Question is - can I automatically put the substitutions even if in the $\sin$ and $\cos$ there is $2x$ inside instead of "classic" $x$?

for example if it was $3\sin(x)$ then $\sin x = 2u/(1+u^2)$?

Comment: Do you mean $\int\frac{ 1-3\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)} \, dx$?

Comment: yes, sorry having trouble with the math equations writer

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: fixed it now @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Not quite: you should use \sin rather than sin. Also the rest of the posting remains unfixed.

Comment: Using an initial substitution $z=2x$ gives $$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1-3\sin(z)}{1+\cos(z)}dz.$$ The original integral also simplifies nicely by applying the identities $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just replace $\sin2x=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$. To convince yourself, just do $z=2x$ first.

Answer (score 0):

Using that $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$ and $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$ we get for the integral $$\int\frac{1}{2\cos^2(x)}-\frac{3\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}dx$$